# Always show first two rows in dynamic collapse using jquery

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a page with multiple divs of same class, i am dynamically adding collapse classes for the all the divs using the below code , but my issue i always want to show first two paragraphs.

here is my code :

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="section-title"></div>
<div class="section-text"></div>

<div class="section-title"></div>
<div class="section-text"></div> 

<div class="section-title"></div>
<div class="section-text"></div>
```

my javascript :

```
   var numItems = $('.section-title').length;
    console.log(numItems );
    var i;
    for(i='0';i<numItems;i++) {
        $(".section-title ").attr("data-toggle", "collapse");
        $(".section-title ").attr("data-target", "#collapseOne"+i);
        $(".section-text ").attr("data-toggle", "collapse");
        $(".section-text").attr("id", "collapseOne"+i);
    }
    $(".section-title ").addClass("toggle");
    $( ".section-text" ).css("display", "none");
    $(".toggle").click(function()
    {

        // hides children divs if shown, shows if hidden
    $(this).next().toggle();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding setAttribute in your code. The `setAttribute()` method adds the specified attribute to an element, and gives it the specified value.

```
$sectionText.setAttribute("data-toggle", "collapse");
```

Update your js with this:

```
$(function(){


  const $sections = $('.section-title')

  for (let i = 0; i< $sections.length; i++){

    const $section = $sections.eq(i)
    const $sectionText = $section.next()

    $section.text(`Section ${i}`)
    $sectionText.text(`Section Text ${i}`)

    const targetId = `section_${i}`
    $sectionText.attr('id',targetId)
    $sectionText.addClass('collapse')
    $sectionText.setAttribute("data-toggle", "collapse");

    $section.attr('data-target',`#${targetId}`)

  }

})
```

Comment: can you give solution to updated code and first two paragraphs should always show

Comment: just replace the JS code with your code. It will run